# How AC current is distributed to our homes?

Tags: ac, generator

I apologize in advance if this is a basic or a silly question. When an AC current is generated by a motor,the current is generated in the loop that is rotating in magnetic field. The current direction varies at each cycle and when it enters the circuit. as is shown here [image]

Reference: https://www.myodesie.com/wiki/index/returnEntry/id/3081

The direction of the current that goes through R has different directions at each cycle hence we have an AC current. Now when I look at the big picture of how the AC current gets distributed to get to our homes, I can't get my head around it. Let's say we have a cable that transfers AC current, does it mean that the current direction keeps changing in the wire?

Comment: Yes​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: 50 or 60 times per second (or 400 times in aircrafts). Waves.

Comment: And the reason that AC won out over DC transmission was that transformers could step the voltages up to high voltage for transmission. Since \$P = V \cdot I \$ (where P is power, V is the voltage and I the current) the same power can be transmitted at high voltage with lower current so less power is lost in the resistance of the cables. Closer to the load - your house, for example - another transformer would step it back down to a lower voltage - 110 V or 230 V, depending on country.

Comment: Current is speed of charge carries. In half cycle the speed is more in one wire (say +ve) relative to the other (-ve) and in other the speed in second is more relative to other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does, 60 times in North America and 50 times a second in Europe and the UK. This is called the **frequency**. It helped me get my head around it faster by instead of thinking of it as AC, thinking of it as DC whose + and - terminals keep switching around at the frequency.

Comment: But instead of using + and - in AC, the wires are called hot and neutral.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, current is not distributed to our homes.

Instead, voltage is distributed.

The AC voltage (alternating voltage) is sent to distant consumers.  If they wish, they can connect various loads (resistors) across the pair of wires, and then these resistors *draw* a current from the system.

Or in more detail:  the generator charges the two wires as if they were capacitor plates.  A momentary current appears, and in this way some electrical energy flows into the wire-pair and is stored as e-fields in the space between wires.  Next, when a distant consumer connects a load resistance, this load then discharges the wire-pair.  A momentary current appears, and the electrical energy flows from the wire-pair and into the distant appliance.  The voltage across the wires starts to decrease as the wires become discharged.  The generator at the other end will see this falling voltage, and will then re-charge the wire-pair to bring the voltage back up again.

Use of energy by the consumer is a give-and-take process between the generator charging up the wires, and the consumer discharging them.  In such a "constant voltage system," each distant appliance acts like a "leakage" between the oppositely-charged wires.  The voltage across the wires remains constant, while the conductors' charges are flowing in proportion to the number of appliances which are turned on, and their parallel resistance (the amount of "leakage.")

Notice that the term "constant voltage system" applies to both AC and DC.

By "constant voltage" we mean constant-voltage-variable-current, where the generator produces a particular voltage, and then the distant consumers can draw any current, including zero.

But yes, as you might suspect, some very early experimental systems used constant current instead of constant voltage.  (Constant-current-variable-voltage.)  In those systems, everything was backwards: all the distant appliances were wired in series, not parallel, and you'd short out an appliance in order to turn it off.  (Typical appliances were arc lamps, or non-carbon metal-filament light bulbs.)  In those systems the AC generator really did send out current to all distant users.  High current, at low or zero voltage depending on how many appliances were switched on.  Then the consumers could draw energy from the grid by un-shorting an appliance and allowing it produce a back-voltage.   This power grid, rather than being like a pair of charged wires (a capacitor,) instead would be a closed loop of wire with a large circulating current (an inductor.)  And, to "discharge" an inductor, we insert a resistor into the closed loop.   In a constant-current system the current is always the same, and the distant consumers can create whatever voltage they need, including zero.

PS

Electric circuits are nearly impossible to visualize unless we've been taught that all wires are already full of movable electricity, while batteries and generators are "electricity pumps."  This is the charge-centric explanation, also called Hydraulic Analogy, or "full pipes scenario."   A generator is a charge-pump which pulls electricity in through one wire, then forces electricity to flow through the generator coils and back out through the rest of the circuit.  If wires are like blood-filled arteries, then a battery is like your heart, and electrons are the blood cells.  The heart does not produce any blood, just as generators can never "generate electricity."  Instead, batteries and generators just pump electricity in a closed-loop flow, and the total quantity of electricity in the circuit is not changing.  The electrons (the movable electricity) is supplied by the conductor's atoms: it's the so-called "sea of charge" found in all metals.